# disconnected set in Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ideals, zariski-topology

Suppose that $V$ is a nonempty affine algebraic set. If $k[V]$ is the direct sum of two non-zero ideals, prove that V is disconnected in the Zariski topology.

I am preparing for the midterm, and I stuck on this problem.

If $k[V]=\frac{k[A^n]}{I(V)}=A+B$ sum of ideals then how can I connect that with connectedness of set $V$?

Thank you!

Comment: Is $k[V]$ the field of rational functions or the coordinate ring?

Comment: @happymath it is the coordinate ring

Comment: It seems that you can write $V$ as a disjoint collection of two Zariski closed set.

Comment: @JohnMa yes, but I could not see which sets exactly

Comment: $\{x\in V: f(x) = 0 \forall f\in A\}$ and similar for $B$?

Comment: @JohnMa yes, but may be they will have nonempty intersection ?

Comment: @JohnMa i see, they would not. Otherwise this point is in both $I(V)$ and its coordinate ring

Comment: @JohnMa but how to show that these sets are nonempty itself?

Comment: @MacStudent these sets are non empty by Hilbert Nullstellensatz since it is a proper ideal(If we assume $K$ is algebraically closed) but I do not see why the union of the two sets is $V$

Comment: @happymath exactly! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let $y\in V$ and $m_y = \{f\in k[V] : f(y) = 0\}$ be the maximal ideal corresponding to $y$. Then $m_y = I_1 \oplus I_2 \subset A \oplus B$. But either $I_1 = A$ or $I_2 = B$ as $m_y$ is maximal. Thus $y$ is in the union of that two closed sets.